# Reading from Multiple MongoDBs to form Dataset

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to make 2 datasets from 2 different Mongo Databases. I am currently using official MongoSpark Connector. sparkSession is started in the following way.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn").setAppName("test")
                        .set("spark.mongodb.input.partitioner", "MongoShardedPartitioner")
                        .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://192.168.77.62/db1.coll1")
                        .set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true");
SparkSession sparkSession = sparkSession.builder().appName("test1").config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();
```

If I want to change the spark.mongodb.input.uri, how will I do that? I have already tried changing the runtimeConfig of sparkSession and also using ReadConfig with readOverrides but those did not work.

Method 1:

```
sparkSession.conf().set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://192.168.77.63/db1.coll2");
```

Method 2:

```
Map<String, String> readOverrides = new HashMap<String, String>();
readoverrides.put("uri","192.168.77.63/db1.coll2");
ReadConfig readConfig = ReadConfig.create(sparkSession).withOptions(readOverrides);
Dataset<Position> ds = MongoSpark.load(sparkSession, readConfig, Position.class);
```

Edit 1: As suggested by Karol I tried the following method

```
  SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn").setAppName("test");
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("test1").config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();
    Map<String, String> readOverrides1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            readOverrides1.put("uri", "mongodb://192.168.77.62:27017");
            readOverrides1.put("database", "db1");
            readOverrides1.put("collection", "coll1");
            ReadConfig readConfig = ReadConfig.create(sparkSession).withOptions(readOverrides1);
```

This fails in runtime saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing database name. Set via the 'spark.mongodb.input.uri' or 'spark.mongodb.input.database' property
```

Edit 2:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("test")
            .config("spark.worker.cleanup.enabled", "true").config("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR").getOrCreate();
    String mongoURI2 = "mongodb://192.168.77.63:27017/db1.coll1";
    Map<String, String> readOverrides1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    readOverrides1.put("uri", mongoURI2);
    ReadConfig readConfig1 = ReadConfig.create(sparkSession).withOptions(readOverrides1);
    MongoSpark.load(sparkSession,readConfig1,Position.class).show();
}
```

Still this is giving the same exception as the previous edit.

Answer (score 2):

built.sbt:
 `libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.spark" % "mongo-spark-connector_2.11" % "2.0.0"`

```
 package com.example.app

 import com.mongodb.spark.config.{ReadConfig, WriteConfig}
 import com.mongodb.spark.sql._

object App {


 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val MongoUri1 = args(0).toString
    val MongoUri2 = args(1).toString
    val SparkMasterUri= args(2).toString

     def makeMongoURI(uri:String,database:String,collection:String) = (s"${uri}/${database}.${collection}")

   val mongoURI1 = s"mongodb://${MongoUri1}:27017"
   val mongoURI2 = s"mongodb://${MongoUri2}:27017"

   val CONFdb1 = makeMongoURI(s"${mongoURI1}","MyColletion1,"df")
   val CONFdb2 = makeMongoURI(s"${mongoURI2}","MyColletion2,"df")

   val WRITEdb1: WriteConfig =  WriteConfig(scala.collection.immutable.Map("uri"->CONFdb1))
   val READdb1: ReadConfig = ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> CONFdb1))

   val WRITEdb2: WriteConfig =  WriteConfig(scala.collection.immutable.Map("uri"->CONFdb2))
   val READdb2: ReadConfig = ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> CONFdb2))

   val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("AppMongo")
  .config("spark.worker.cleanup.enabled", "true")
  .config("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
  .getOrCreate()

   val df1 = spark.read.mongo(READdb1)
   val df2 = spark.read.mongo(READdb2)
   df1.write.mode("overwrite").mongo(WRITEdb1)
   df2.write.mode("overwrite").mongo(WRITEdb2)

 }

}
```

you can now pass `uri1` and `uri2` into `/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit pathToMyjar.app.jar MongoUri1 MongoUri2 sparkMasterUri`as args and then create `config` for each `uri`

```
spark.read.mongo(READdb)
```

Comment: But sparkSession needs to have a mongodb uri while initializing the ReadConfig. I tried using 2 ReadConfigs but it failed in runtime saying it needs a uri for SparkSession

Comment: And if I pass one uri to SparkSession I cannot overwrite it using ReadConfig.

Comment: But if I dont set mongo config in sparkSession my readConfig is also not created. Please go through the edit I've made in the question. I did not set mongo config in spark session

Comment: hey, edited code, so that you can see full app with mongo config set up independently from spark config

Comment: I made a new edit. Please have a look at it. I am using java. I am just trying to provide the uri through ReadConfig without any changes to SparkSession. Can you please check it. Also in your code you used sparkSession.read.mongo() method. I did not find a Java equivalent of it. Can you also please help me on that

Comment: This is the working answer. Too bad the official mongo guide does not include such an obvious case.

Answer (score 0):

It's not useful to set uri in ReadConfig. Spark-Mongo connector uses this information when call ReadConfig.create() method. So try to set it in SparkContext  before use it.

Just like below:

```
SparkContext context = spark.sparkContext();
context.conf().set("spark.mongodb.input.uri","mongodb://host:ip/database.collection");
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(context);
```